# Accessing C++ class public member function from private struct data member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, access-specifier, pimpl-idiom

This might be a trivial C++ semantics question, I guess, but I'm running into issues on Windows (VS2010) with this. I have a class as follows:

```
class A {
public:
   some_type some_func();
private: 
   struct impl;
   boost::scoped_ptr<impl> p_impl;
}
```

I'd like to access the function `some_func` from within a function defined in the `struct impl` like so:

```
struct A::impl {
   impl(..) {} //some constructor
   ...
   some_impl_type some_impl_func() {
     some_type x = some_func(); //-Need to access some_func() here like this
   }
};
```

The VS 2010 contextual menu shows an error so didn't bother building yet:

```
Error: A non-static member reference must relative to a specific object
```

I'd be surprised if there was no way to get to the public member function. Any ideas on how to get around this are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance of `A`. `A::impl` is a different struct than `A`, so the implicit `this` is not the right instance. Pass one in in the constructor:

```
struct A::impl {
   impl(A& parent) : parent_(parent) {} //some constructor
   ...
   some_impl_type some_impl_func() {
     some_type x = parent_.some_func(); //-Need to access some_func() here like this
   }

   A& parent_;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I figured the implicit this shouldn't work because it would instead point to impl, but still seems weird I have to do this, given the call comes from an object of A which in turn calls the impl member function.